# Why cant we have multiple compareTo functions in a class like we can have multiple compare functions?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

```
import java.util.Comparator;
class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{
    private int rn;
    private float cg;
    private String name;
    public Student(int num, float cgpa, String nm)
    {
        rn = num; cg = cgpa; name = nm;
}
public int getrn()
{   return rn;
}
public float getcg()
{   return cg;
}
public String getname()
{   return name;
}
public static class orderbyrn implements Comparator<Student>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Student obj1, Student obj2)
    {
        return obj1.rn>obj2.rn? 1 : (obj1.rn<obj2.rn? -1 : 0 );
    }
}
public static class orderbycg implements Comparator<Student>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Student obj1, Student obj2)
    {
        return obj1.cg>obj2.cg? 1 : (obj1.cg<obj2.cg? -1 : 0 );
    }
}
/*  NOTE THIS FAILS TO COMPILE!
public static class testingcomparable implements Comparable<Student>
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student obj)
    {
        return cg>obj2.cg? 1 : (cg<obj2.cg? -1 : 0 );
    }
}
*/
@Override
public int compareTo(Student obj2)  //while overriding types have to be compatible ie either same or related by inheritance
{
    return rn>obj2.rn? 1 : (rn<obj2.rn? -1 : 0 );
}
public String toString()
{
    return rn+name+cg;
}
}
```

The error displayed is :
"non-static variable cg cannot be referenced from a static context"
I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
Pardon me if I am not clear enough. First time posting a question! :D

Comment: Your question title is unrelated to your actual problem. There are already a huge number of questions on SO regarding "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context", you should look at some of them...

Comment: declare static the variable first of all and than go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you are referencing the `cg` field of your `Student` class from within a nested static class `testingcomparable` - which can't see the instance fields of your `Student` class. `orderbycg` works becuase it references the `cg` fields on the objects `obj1` and `obj2`.

Answer (score 0):

The essential difference between `Comparable` and `Comparator` is that the former defines ***the*** *natural order* for a class. Note the definite article in that sentence: there can be only one natural order. On the other hand, you can implement `Comparator` any number of times to define other arbitarry orders for the same class.

Note how the above is reflected in the method signatures: `compareTo()` takes only one other object, assuming `this` as the left-hand side. You attempted to implement it in a separate class, where `this` does not refer to a `Student`, and that's the proximate reason why your code failed to compile.